# GitHub pages shows my site as unsafe (red window)

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

I am using GitHub pages to deploy a website I made, however when I view the deployment, it shows that the site is unsafe and I have to go to details and select the proceed to site anyways option every time. Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You use a custom domain? The first thing i would try is wait 1h: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/troubleshooting-custom-domains-and-github-pages#https-errors

Comment: Domain names are kinda expensive, am not able to afford at the moment :( This issue has been there for at least a month now

Comment: Oh i thought its unsafe because of an untrusted ssl certificate. But i now visited the site and its some other unsafe warning.

Comment: Ya, I don't know how to fix it